# Printing hex data and redirecting into file from command line with python 2.x and python 3.x

Tags: python, linux, hex, command-line-interface

So I'm trying to write data into a file by redirecting the output of `print` into it.

In Python 2.x, I did it as `python -c "print '\x80'" > myFile`.

Checking the hexdump with `xxd myFile` properly displays `800a` (ignore the newline `0a`).

In Python 3.x, I am trying to do it as `python3 -c "print('\x80')" > myFile`.

This time, however, the hexdump is `c280 0a`.

After attempting a few workarounds, I notice that this only happens to values greater or equal to (decimal) `128`.

`python3 -c "print('\x7f')" > myFile` properly writes `7f0a`.

What I'm looking for is a way for me to write it like that in Python 3.x while avoiding, for example, converting from hex to dec myself.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it happens because Python 2 has two similar sequences [types](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange): strings and Unicode strings, which corresponds to the `str` and `unicode` respectively.

So in Python 2 you could encode the string:

```
>>> u = unichr(0x80)
>>> u.encode('utf-8')
>>> '\xc2\x80'
```

But in Python 3 all the strings are Unicode strings and `print('\x80')` returns `'\xc2\x80'` which is UTF-8 representation of `U+0080` unicode code point.